# simple database engine for data manipulation

Tags: database

I have a bunch of data in text format and I need to do some analysis on it. I think SQL will be very efficient but  don't want to install a server (like sql server or mysql) all I need is a simple engine I can import the data into and then do a few queries (from the local machine)

is there such a database ?

Comment: Need information about the data and what you hope to do with it to advise effectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Here is an [ADO.NET Provider](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Is your data tabular? Or is it just text files? If just text files you might want to try a full text indexing search engine such as Lucene (versions available for Java and .NET).

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows you can use an Excel spreadsheet as your database and declare it to be an ODBC data source. The tools for this are probably in "System Settings | Administration" or so.

You can then download a simple ODBC SQL client to do your queries on this source. I found a few of those by Googling for `ODBC SQL client`.